# Include css stylesheet in electron app

Tags: html, css, electron

I created a style.css file. To include it in a .html file I tried :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.com/karinakozarova/HealthCalc/blob/master/style.css">
```

and

```
<base href="/style.css">
```

and

```
<href="/style.css">
```

None of them seem to work. Any ideas how to add CSS to my app via external file will be appreciated.

Comment: I know nothing about electron app,  i"m a web developer,  i just googled this,  pls read this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879290/electron-app-isnt-finding-css-js-included-in-package

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you may be missing a "type" attribute within that link. Try the markup below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://github.com/karinakozarova/HealthCalc/blob/master/style.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub "blob" urls are webpages showing your file. Not the file itself. So you need to use the "raw" url or something like jsDelivr.