# Using Electron with Reactstrap causes error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, electron, reactstrap

When attempting to use the `reactstrap` package in an [Electron boilerplate app](https://github.com/jschr/electron-react-redux-boilerplate) by first installing the npm packages

```
npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom
npm install bootstrap --save
```

then importing the Bootstrap CSS in `/app/renderer/app.js`

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

we are getting the error in the JS console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Removing the `import` statement for bootstrap CSS removes the error, but the app ends up with no Bootstrap CSS styling.

**Question:** How can we get `reactstrap` to work properly in an Electron app?

Comment: Can you check if you have css loader configured in your webpack?

Comment: @aks I think the boilerplate code does not use webpack. Having not setup webpack from scratch before, is there a simpler way than installing webpack and configuring css loader?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this easily. The best route would be to configure the current setup to allow for css. What is it using? Gulp? Here is one useful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879290/electron-app-isnt-finding-css-js-included-in-package

Comment: @aks I believe it is not using gulp as well. The boilerplate code was created using [electron builder](https://www.electron.build/).

Answer (score 1):

The basic electron setup doesn't understand CSS, therefor it fails at loading a CSS file.

Instead you could add the following line into the `<head>` section of the `.index.html` file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

The electron app (a special Chromium web browser instance) will load the CSS.